# jQuery changing the id attribute of all the children

Tags: jquery

I need some help figuring out how to write some jQuery code.

I need to clone a table dynamically onclick. but then I need to change the ids of the table and its child elements each time. as the table can have lots of children it will be to difficult to do this manually. I need a way to change the id's of all child(all descendants) elements. I will always just add the counter to the id. (I know children will access only the immediate children but I just wanted to try if that works). If you guys know how this can be done in either jQuery or Javascript, please let me know.

```
<table id="table"> 
    <tr id = "tr" > 
        <td id="td"> 
            <span id="span" value="hiii">hi</span> 
        </td> 
    </tr>
</table> 

<button>Clone</button> 

<script> 
    $("button").click(function () { 
        var table = $("#table").clone(true,true) 
        table.attr( 'id', function() { return this.id +"1"; })    
        alert($("#table1").children()) 
        $("#table1").find(*).attr('id', function() { return this.id +"1"; }) 
        table.appendTo("#table") 
        alert(document.getElementById("tr1")) 
        alert(document.getElementById("span1").value) 
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: <table id="table">
 <tr id = "tr" >
   <td id="td">
        <span id="span" value="hiii">hi</span>
                </td>
                 </tr></table>



    <button>Clone</button>
    <script>

     $("button").click(function () {
     var table = $("#table").clone(true,true)
     table.attr( 'id', function() { return this.id +"1"; })
     alert($("#table1").children())
     $("#table1").find(*).attr('id', function() { return this.id +"1"; })
     table.appendTo("#table")
     alert(document.getElementById("tr1"))
     alert(document.getElementById("span1").value)
    });

Comment: Why did you put that into a comment?

Comment: I am not able to insert the code though even after indenting it (I am new to this forum). I'll try to get a screen shot though

Comment: it looks to me like you're already on the right lines, except that it's not legal to use a purely numeric value as an element's ID.

Comment: Hi Alnitak I am attaching the number as a row id to the name

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `elem` is the parent of your cloned structure and `cntr` is the counter you said you were maintaining, you can fix all ids in that cloned structure like this:

```
function fixIds(elem, cntr) {
    $(elem).find("[id]").add(elem).each(function() {
        this.id = this.id + cntr;
    })
}
```

If the ids might already have a cloned number at the end and you want to replace that number, you can do so like this:

```
function fixIds(elem, cntr) {
    $(elem).find("[id]").add(elem).each(function() {
        this.id = this.id.replace(/\d+$/, "") + cntr;
    })
}
```

So, based on the code you've now added to your question, you could do this:

```
<script> 
    var cloneCntr = 1;
    $("button").click(function () { 
        var table = $("#table").clone(true,true) 
        fixIds(table, cloneCntr);
        table.insertAfter("#table") 
        cloneCntr++;
    });
</script>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/wFu9K/

Note: I also changed the DOM insertion code to `insertAfter()`, because you can't append one table to another the way you were doing (a table would either go after the existing table or inside a cell in the previous table).

---

If you are just trying to add a row, then you need to clone the row, not the whole table.

You could add a cloned row to the existing table with this code:

```
function fixIds(elem, cntr) {
    $(elem).find("[id]").add(elem).each(function() {
        this.id = this.id.replace(/\d+$/, "") + cntr;
    })
}
var cloneCntr = 1;
$("button").click(function () { 
    var row = $("#table tr").first().clone(true,true);
    fixIds(row, cloneCntr++);
    row.appendTo("#table") 
}); ​
```

Comment: Hi jfriend Thanks for your reply. I am trying to copy thta code onto my notepad and  run it on firefox it doenst work. also when I did a alert on id span1 (on Fiddle) i am not getting the alert.  do you have any idea why?

Comment: @LakshmikanthanVijayaraghavan - Without seeing your actual code/page, I don't know what you did so I can't comment on what isn't right.  You can see from the jsFiddle links that the code works and runs when implemented properly.  If you put your actual code into a jsFiddle and post the link to that jsFiddle, we can take a look at your specific code.

Comment: @ JFriend Yeah even the alert works. I think I know why my code wont work , you have done a $(window).load can you tell me why? and will the values of html elements also get copies when I do a clone. Ill put my code on Fiddle and check too Thanks a lot

Comment: @LakshmikanthanVijayaraghavan - For the second time, without seeing your code that doesn't work, I can't tell you what's wrong with it.  Popular guesses are: 1) You didn't include jQuery, 2) Your code is running before the DOM is loaded, 3) You have a javascript syntax error causing your code to abort and stop running.  Have you at least looked in the javascript error console to see if it is reporting errors?

Comment: @ JFreind Hi I finally figured out how to use the Fiddlet hing here si the link to my code http://jsfiddle.net/lakshmikanthanv/5Lrvq/

Comment: @LakshmikanthanVijayaraghavan - You need to do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5Lrvq/2/

Comment: @LakshmikanthanVijayaraghavan - as you're fairly new to StackOverflow, do you realize that when someone provides you an answer that answers your question, you should click the checkmark to the left of that answer?  That indicates to the StackOverflow community which answer best answered your question and it earns the answerer some reputation points for providing the answer and earns you some reputation points for following the right procedure on StackOverflow.

Comment: Hi Jfriend Sorry I din't know how it worked but I checked it now

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#table1").find(*)
```

should be

```
table.find("*")
```

`$("#table1")` will not return anything on that line of code as you have not yet added the table to the DOM.  And `*` is a selector which should be a string.

Comment: Hi James Yeah I fixed that, but it will still not give me a object on my alert of "tr1", it gives me a null and my third alert (with value) doesn get called. Will be great if u help out with that.

Comment: Answer updated.  `#table1` can't be found as you have not yet appended it.

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
$Element.children().each(function () {
        this.id = new_id;
 });
```