# Change complex id value in Jquery Clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

This is my input field

```
<input class="form-control" id="StudentInstitutes_0__Name" name="StudentInstitutes[0].Name" value="" type="text">
```

I use `clone()` to the div wrapping the above input field. That works fine.

But how can I change the id & name index which is "0" in above  with the button click.

Ex: if I click button for the first time the input field will be:

```
<input class="form-control" id="StudentInstitutes_1__Name" name="StudentInstitutes[1].Name" value="" type="text">
```

This is my button

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="button" name="ShowMoreInstitution" id="ShowMore" value="Add More Institution" onclick="javascript:  showMoreInstitution();" />
    </div>                                       
</div>
```

This is my JS

```
$("#showMore").click(function () {
    $('#showInstitute').clone().insertAfter("#showInstitute");
});
```

Note that I am using Asp.net Mvc Razor view and don't want to use partial view for the operation.

Comment: Suggest you refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026374/adding-another-pet-to-a-model-form/24027152#24027152) (create a template and clone that (and the `id` attributes are pointless for you case, so better to just delete them - its the `name` attribute which is important)

Comment: PS: Unless you have VBScript on the page as the first script, you do NOT need `javascript: ` in the onclick handler

Comment: What is the onclick doing - please remove it. Also click `<>` and create a [mcve] since your code as shown does not work at all - where is showInstitute? If you save the clone and change the name/ID using regex before inserting it it should be simple

Comment: solved the problem.thanks @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 0):

As I come to know that you wants to change id dynamically, so you have to first declare global variable "value" and assign initial value to it 0.

```
$("#showMore").click(function () {
    value++;
    $('#showInstitute').removeAttr('id').attr('id', 'StudentInstitutes_" + value + "__Name');
});
```

this code may help you.

Comment: if i use clone() then how to use it to set "id" attribute?

Comment: I don't have exact idea about it but I think this link may help you [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33437891/change-inner-elements-id-during-clone] @Fahad